# Loop enters infinite loop if cout is missing

Tags: c++, string, while-loop, infinite-loop, endl

I have encountered something very strange.  The code I am having trouble with is:

```
int stringPos;
int found1;
while (stringPos < 1);
{
    //start searching inString for framen starting at foundn and record
    found1 = inString.find(frame1, found1);
    cout << found1 << endl;


    //if return is a number, push back foundn to a vector
    if (found1 != -1)
    {
        foundPositions.push_back(found1);
    }
    //if return is npos, then break the loop
    else
    {
        stringPos=1;
    }

    //add 1 to foundn so that the search would continue from where the
    //search ended last
    found1+=1;
}
```

The strange thing is that when I put `cout << found1 << endl;` below the line `found1 = inString.find(frame1, found1);` the loop executes properly.  However, if I don't have the `cout << found1 << endl;` it enters an infinite loop...

Any suggestions?  THANKS!

Comment: That code doesn't do what you claim it does.  And if you won't show us the code with the problem, how could we fix it?

Comment: Please read and think about http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a mistake (and uses an unitialized variable):

```
while (stringPos < 1);
```

as it is equivalent to:

```
while (stringPos < 1) {}
```

*If* this did not enter an infinite loop the code following it would be executed once only. To correct:

- Initialize the variables `stringPos` and `found1`.
- Use type `size_t` for `stringPos` and `found` as [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) does not return an `int`, but returns `size_type` (usually `size_t`).
- Use [`std::string::npos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) instead of `-1` to test for *not found*.
- Remove the trailing semi-colon.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has undefined behavior, because you are trying to use the value of an uninitialized variable here:

```
while (stringPos < 1)
//     ^^^^^^^^^
//     This is uninitialized
```

And here:

```
found1 = inString.find(frame1, found1);
//                             ^^^^^^
//                             This is uninitialized
```

Besides, even supposing your variables were initialized, you have a semicolon that makes your `while` loop either a no-op or an infinite loop ([as hmjd correctly points out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16926147/1932150)).

Answer (score 0):

I would start off by initializing the stringPos and found1 variables.